# Taxonomy terms can't find posts from archive.php or taxonomy.php

Tags: taxonomy, archives, terms

I've displayed all of my custom taxonomy terms and links with get_terms(). When I click on those links then they redirect me to archive.php. But in archive.php, it can't found any posts from those terms without WP_Query().
But my archive.php is ok for displaying posts from category or others.
I can't understand what is the problem. It seems all things are right. 
Can anyone please give me a solution to solve this?

Comment: Have you flushed permalinks?

Comment: Yes. But yet can't found any posts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was happened for using public => false, when registering my post type. So, always use public => true, has_archieve => true & with_front => true if you want to display your single custom posts.